# Salesforce DX User License Requirements

Tags: licenses, salesforcedx

With the recent documentation it looks like Salesforce DX is leveraging the main business org to function. This is a big departure from registering for free users for developer orgs (we don't have full Salesforce users for all of our developers since these licenses are very expensive).

Their [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm) specifies that you must create standard users for team members to leverage scratch orgs (a huge part of DX). Does anyone that was a part of the pilot know if this is actually the case?

Comment: It looks like those developer orgs with dx support are just 30 day trials. Also I am a bit confused about the "still the case" in your answer. Today we use branch orgs which are created from our partner packaging org which has 20 free full licenses (this is not our business org but the org from which we publish). We can create a branch org for each developer and that developer can then work in that org. With the DX setup it looks as though each of our 20 developers will instead need a full license in our business org (which would be paid).

Comment: Honestly unsure. I'm not familiar enough with the setup of partner orgs to be able to provide input of value. That comment you made seems to be your real question, however. Have you also tried asking this in the [Success Community group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1)? They might be of more help, since some of the team members for SFDX should be in the group.

Comment: Great idea, I'll post this over there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some unofficial clarification on this from the DX team at TrailheaDX. They said that you do need a user for authentication but that is all. Sharing a user among your team should be fine and it won't impact the actual DX functionality at all.

**Edit**

Salesforce now provides a free limited access license that allows partners to create developer accounts with use for DX. See the [setup instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm) for more details.

Comment: Did Salesforce told you about sharing a single license with other developers ? Isn't that against Salesforce MSA ? http://www.salesforce.com/company/msa.jsp

Comment: Yes, it is. We recently have been forced to stop using shared production licenses